# Detect my app's own android:versionCode at run time

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is there a way for my app to know the android:versionCode from AndroidManifest.xml or do I have to create a separate constant in one of my classes?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I put this in my subclassed android.app.Application but you can use it anywhere you have a context.  Just change getPackageManager() to context.getPackageManager().

```
public int getVersion() {
    int v = 0;
    try {
        v = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // Huh? Really?
    }
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access this information via [PackageManager.getPackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Also, see details about versioning in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can get version code simply from `<package_name>.BuildConfig#VERSION_CODE`
reference. It is generated by ADT plugin/Intellij.