# How to know if APK file is newer than the installed one?

Tags: android, apk, android-applicationinfo

I am making an app to be updated from my own home page. I made the update procedure and works fine.

Now, I want the update to proceed only if the APK on my page is newer than the installed one. By newer, I mean newer with respect to date installed, or to the size of the APKs being just different. I always forget to update the version name...

So: how do I retrieve the date of installation of an installed APK, or the date of the file of an installed APK, or the size of the APK (/data/app dir requires root access, that I don't want my users to need)?

I know about ApplicationInfo and PackageManager, but didn't find the information I need in their documentation.

Thanks!
L.

Comment: Version name? or you mean number right? It's the number that is crucial... just don't forget to update it... DUH

Comment: @AndersMetnik: Maybe I wasn't clear? I don't want to use the versionName (yes, it is 'versionName', as it has to be written in the manifest file).

Answer (score 1):

Find out the answer by myself. See below if interested.

```
public long appinfo(String pkg){
    PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager();
    long labeldate = 0;
    try {
        PackageInfo label = p.getPackageInfo(pkg, 0);
        labeldate = label.lastUpdateTime;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return labeldate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311644/get-application-installed-date-on-android) is what you are looking for.

FYI, you should probably be using [Android's practices for versioning.](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html) This seems like a counter productive work-around to try to not have to remember to bump up a version. Ultimately date of installation and size of your .apk are NEVER going to be sure bets as to whether you application is newer or older, since you .apk could shrink in size if you remove code, and someone could have a much older version, but installed it after whatever minimum date you are looking for.

I advise using a version code rather than version name to determine if an application is newer, since version names can be an arbitrary string, but version codes are a simple integer comparison. [This is a clear SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874775/detect-my-apps-own-androidversioncode-at-run-time).

Comment: Thanks, I already found a way below (forgot to press "SEND"). One problem with versioning is that you need to retrieve the APK to get it, while getting the modification time/size are simple and small http queries. In the worst case, the user will install twice the same apk. Anyway, I update the versionCode, but I am now releasing several versions/day, so half the times I forget. Not practical by now... thanks for the advice!