# How can I set the notification in android application to update next version

Tags: android

I have upload apk with `version 1.0.0.0`.  I want to upload next `version 1.0.0.1.`how can I set the notification to inform the user that my application has a newer version available on Google play. Can any one suggest me how to do it?

Comment: Google Play will be automatically send notification to the user dude

Answer (score 1):

Found in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874775/detect-my-apps-own-androidversioncode-at-run-time/3874816#3874816) (duplicated??)

```
public int getVersion() {
    int v = 0;
    try {
        v = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // Huh? Really?
    }
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question to be "How does one determine if the play store has a newer version than the one installed".

I don't know of an official way to lookup an app's version in the Play Store. The most common solution I've seen for this requirement is to host the version number on a server somewhere and do a web request to get it.

There's a library at https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ that purports to do the Play Store lookup, (among other things) but I don't have **any** experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to configure something called **`Firebase Cloud Messaging`** and enable notification. Here is the complete guide on [how to](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience).